# CVS does not recognize that CVSROOT is set in .bashrc and .bash_profile

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, cvs

I'm trying to set up cvs on my account on a school computer (Profs recommend we use it).  But, I have already had it installed on this account before, but for some reason it is not working. So I'm trying to go through the setup process again and figure out whats wrong.  Here's a quick snippit of the instructions they gave:

```
a. edit .bashrc and .bash_profile to add this line:
    export CVSROOT=$HOME/CVS
b. issue these commands to create the master CVS repo dir:
    echo $CVSROOT   # confirm that CVSROOT is set
```

And thats where it breaks.  Even tho I've added the line from step a in .bashrc and .bash_profile, CVS still will not recognize that my CVSROOT is set. When I execute the command `echo $CVSROOT`, I get no output.

```
mdw7326@newyork:~$ echo $CVSROOT

mdw7326@newyork:~$
```

I've tried researching for myself but so far I have been unlucky so far.  I know my way around linux but I'm no Guru and I'm hoping someone with a little more expertise has seen this problem before.  I'm not sure if it is entirely relevant but im on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-58-generic-pae i686)

[UPDATE]

when I display env CVSROOT IS in the list of variables

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with the question, but do you have an option of using another version control system in place of CVS? There are many modern and distributed version control systems available today which are much better than CVS in many ways (e.g. git)

Comment: I'd have to ask my instructor about that but I think the answer would be no from my experience in pas cs courses here.  The cs department is really strict about using cvs and try.

Comment: @user3276397 What does 'echo $SHELL' say?

Comment: @PeterL. the output for 'echo $SHELL' is '/bin/bash'

Comment: @mdw7326 Did you try opening a new shell?  Try echoing something from your .bashrc to show that it is being sourced.

Comment: @PeterL. I inserted 'x=4' into my .bashrc file, then issued the command 'echo $x'. The result was a blank line. Is this what you were asking me to do?

Comment: @mdw7326 Try 'echo Test from ~/.bashrc'.  Note that you should start a new shell and see if that appears in your console.

Comment: @PeterL. I got "Test from /home/stu3/s15/mdw7326/.bashrc"

Comment: `export CVSROOT=$HOME/CVS` should really be `export CVSROOT="$HOME/CVS"` to prevent some splitting issues. And `echo $CVSROOT` should be `echo "$CVSROOT"`. And make sure you source whichever dotfile you set it in.

Comment: Also, DO NOT put them in both files, since the dot-files get read in a specific order. So if you put them in both, and then make a change in one, it won't necessarily get propagated to the shell.

Comment: Did the instructions include something like log out and log in again? Try it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CVS just started working again.  After several hours of me being inactive.  I have two theories:

1. I was in a folder which did not have visibility to my CVSROOT variable, so naturally when I went to 
   Test it with `echo $CVSROOT`, it printed nothing. I would've had to do `cd` first, then test it.
2. During the time I was inactive on this machine, a student using the physical machine in the computer
   lab rebooted it for one reason or another which made it work some how (Not too sure about this 
   theory)

But either way it works now, but thanks for trying to help everyone

Answer (score 0):

After editing your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile`, you must log out and then log back in for the changes to take effect.  (Alternatively you could type `source ~/.bashrc` and/or `source ~/.bash_profile`, but it's worth testing your changes the same way you'll be using them in the future -- i.e. by logging in fresh.)

Comment: Absolutely no reason to log-out/log-in when making simple bash dot-file changes.

Comment: @BroSlow Unless of course you want the contents of the file to go into effect ... o.0

Comment: @dg99 There is a reason `source` exists. Logging out/logging back-in shouldn't effect the shell at all unless there are some system-wide problems, restarting the shell would help, but again when the shell starts it `sources` the bash init files, so doing that is enough for the large majority of cases.

Comment: Given that the OP's instructor told him to edit *both* `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` (which is completely pointless in a properly configured system), it stands to reason that the skeleton files in the OP's `~` are possibly less than well-written.  If they are so poorly written as to be non-idempotent, then it could be a very bad idea to simply `source` them over again.  So, better safe than sorry.